# Resize text on wrap with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap, font-size

I'd like to be able to have text which resizes when it wraps so that the total height of the text block is always the same. In other words, if the text wraps to a second line then the font size becomes half the original, and if it wraps to a third line then it becomes a third of the original, etc. Is this possible in CSS or even with Javascript?

Comment: You can use media query. Resize the browser to see when the text wrap and at that measure put a media query where you reduce the font-size

Comment: CSS alone, no. With JS, very much possible. with javascript you need to measure the number of (wrapped) lines (of some element), and act accordingly (decrease font size)

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? There are countless open-source on github which auto-fit texts to their container. What is the UX goal here?

Comment: It's supposed to be for a Next app, the header has a text box for the page title which varies from page to page and the designers want it to shrink when it wraps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use media query or 'vw' to do that.
For example.

HTML

```
<div>
  <span class="resizing">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

CSS using **media query**

```
.resizing {
  font-size: 1rem;
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {  // You can change this breakpoint
    font-size: 0.5rem;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {  // You can also change this breakpoint
    font-size: 0.33rem;
  }
}
```

CSS using **vw**

```
.resizing {
  font-size: 1vw; // 1vw is 1% of the browser width
  font-size: calc(3px + 1vw); // Or you can do something like this.
}
```

I wish it helps you.